# Problems with configuring mysql/mysql-server dockerfile

Tags: mysql, linux, docker, mariadb, dockerfile

I'm a 2nd year applied computer science student and I have some problems with configuring a mysql docker.
As an assignment we have to create 2 docker images (1 with apache/php and a simple php web page and another one with mysql). I've created the apache/php docker already which wasn't that hard, but I struggle quite a lot with the mysql one.

files

```
./Dockerfile
./test.sql
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM mysql/mysql-server

ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=lindert

RUN mkdir /usr/sql
RUN chmod 644 /usr/sql
ADD test.sql /usr/sql/test.sql

run MYSQL -u root -p${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD} -e "CREATE DATABASE \
shippingdb" && mysql -u root -p${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD} shippingdb < 
/usr/sql/test.sql
```

When I run 'docker build .' this error pops up:

```
mysql: [WARNING] Using a password on the command line interface can be 
insecure.
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
'/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I have no clue how to fix this, I've been googling for 3 hours now and I didn't find the answer yet, would be nice if someone could help. 
Thanks!

Comment: I don't believe the sql service is going to be running during the build process. You'll likely want to remove the last RUN command from your dockerfile and let the php container connect and initialize the database, that's not typically something you'd do during the build step, at least in my experience.

Comment: I've had a similar experience with postgres, but this might get you headed in the right direction. I was trying to do something like this during the build, but of course postgres isn't running during the build. Here, you might be attempting to execute a mysql command, but mysql isn't actually running until its [docker-entrypoint.sh](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/master/8.0/docker-entrypoint.sh) fires off when you actually run the image.

Answer (score 0):

Mount your sql file to '/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d' path and it will be imported. Put your 'CREATE DATABASE' call in the sql file

IE: Dockerfile and sql files in your working/root dir

```
FROM mysql/mysql-server

ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=lindert

RUN mkdir /usr/sql
RUN chmod 644 /usr/sql
VOLUME ./ /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

This is mentioned on the docker hub page for the official mysql image
https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/